# stop media session service when the user remove the notification Media3

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, exoplayer, android-media3

I am in the phase where I migrate my app from ExoPlayer to jetpack Media3 and I want to stop my `MediaSessionService` once the user deletes the notification but in the
`MediaNotification.Provider` we could not catch the event when the user deletes the Notification all what we have is to `setDeleteIntent` and here I want to stop the Notification some solutions that I found like write a `BroadcastReciever` and do that in `onRecieve()` method but it looks for me over engineering. Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding onTaskRemoved()? Like -

```
override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
    mediaSession.player.release()
    stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your Answer, but the above method will be triggered when the user stops the App from settings and I already implemented the method and it didn't helped.